how to spy/argumentcaptor of background thread to verify in karate-spring boot application
I've a scenario, API service running in springboot and trying to port the existing functional Test to karate based testing. I've added. the API endpoint based configuration and other validation for response and wire mock for other services. Now I've a situation to validate background threads like few scenario needs fire and forget basics data which needs to be validated and few method calls to log some critical information based. Currently with FunctionalTest we do spy and arugmentCapture to do the assertion but with Karate framework how do I achieve the same behavior of asserting/evaluating those calls argument are safe and good as expected. Please share some insight how to manage the argumentCapture and ResultCapture in the flow of Karate framework based validation.
I tried to understand more documentation how to combine mockito spy and karate but I couldn't find any documentation so I believe both different things can't be merged together in this case I need some help how to achieve the same behavior in karate framework. Is it possible with karate framework ? If this kind of validation required should I avoid in case using karate or should I stick with mockito and junit based springboot functional test

please see if this answers your question: https://x.com/getkarate/status/1417023536082812935
